# My express router post request is not working on postman

Tags: express, postman, router

My express router post request is not working on postman , this is my first time using express router on a project ive been stuck on this error and cant seem to find a way to make the post request work
here is my code
my server.js

```
const express=require('express')

const app=express()

const port=process.env.PORT || 5000

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.json({"msg":"welcome to the server"})
})

//Define Routes
app.use('api/users',require('./routes/users'))
app.use('api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('api/contact', require('./routes/contact'))




app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server is running`))
```

my users.js

```
const express=require('express')
const router=express.Router()

//@route POST api/users
//@desc  Register a user
//@access Public

router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('registers a user')
})

module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/ is missing before route prefixes.

Change `app.use('api/users',require('./routes/users'))` to `app.use('/api/users',require('./routes/users'))`

Comment: thank you very much lol to think it was a /

Comment: Welcome, can you please mark it as accepted answer, it will help me in unlocking basic stackoverflow features.